# How to properly assign generic props when using HoC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a component and this component gets passed to a HOC which should ehance the original component.

I declared a type for the props the component is receiving but I'm still getting the error "TS2741", which says:

```
Property 'auth' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'AppProps'
```

I wrote a little example which you can see here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-huaq8s

So my guess is, that TypeScript checks if `props` from the return function within `withAuth` has the properties declared via our type. This can only fail, since the properties we are checking for are added later (via `<WrappedComponent ... />`)

From my current knowledge my I guess is that I have to somehow tell TypeScript that the returned `WrappedComponent` should be checked for having `P`. But I don't know how to do that.

So obviously before I asked this question, I read a lot of online articles and a few questions here in the forum, but I still couldn't find the answer.

Can someone here help me?

Comment: In your shared example `App` does not seem to be using `withAuth` at all but yet needs `auth` provided as a prop (which you are not providing nor are you wrapping App around anything). I feel like I'm missing some context here

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to wrap `App` with `withAuth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this might be a bit complicated and I'm not 100% confident that this is really the correct way to go but here goes.

The goal here is to wrap a regular component which requires an auth property in a HOC which will provide that auth property. To do this you need your `withAuth` parameter to actually be a component which requires `auth` (as `App` does) and your result will be a component which does not.

Here's how you can achieve that:

```
type Omit<T,U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, U>>; // This is standard since 3.5

interface AuthProps {
  auth: TAuthProviderUtils
}

function withAuth<P extends AuthProps>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>) : ComponentType<Omit<P,keyof AuthProps>> {
  return (props: Omit<P,keyof AuthProps>) => (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {auth => <WrappedComponent {...props} auth={auth} />}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  )
}

// This needs auth
function App<AppProps>({ auth: { user } }) {
  return (
    <div>Hello App</div>
  )
}

const AppWithAuth = withAuth(App); // This does not need auth
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ikftpy?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Just saying that I will mark this answer as correct as soon as I have understood the code :D (I'm quite new to TypeScript)

Comment: I think the bottom line is that `withAuth` when given a component which takes parameters `P` (where `P extends AuthProps`) it returns a new component type which takes the same parameters except for the parameters in `AuthProps` (that's the `Omit` part)

Comment: The stackblitz does not pass typechecking: `'Omit<P, "auth"> & { auth: TAuthProviderUtils; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AuthProps'`

Comment: @CarlG It was working 3 years ago as it was not sure what changed in the meantime. Updated the stackblitz to do a cast which seems to fix it (for some reason)

Comment: I believe it was https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16368 (although that should have landed well before your answer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ (I've been trying to figure this out for myself without the typecast: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74072249/how-to-split-generic-props-between-an-hocs-own-components-and-generic-child)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to pass the AppProps type to withAuth, otherwise the generic you declared is not being used.

i.e.:

```
const AppWithAuth = withAuth<AppProps>(App)
```

Is this what you are looking for?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-uxhgql?file=index.tsx

Comment: I think there is no need for withAuth<AppProps>. You get the same result without it and by removing `: P` from `props`. I solved the issue by just replacing `props: P` with `props: any` in `withAuth`. But I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it.