# How to split generic props between an HOC's own components and generic child?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wcy3ak?file=index.tsx,index.html)

Hi, I am trying to create a React HOC that renders a form for editing different objects.
The HOC accepts a component representing the form fields to edit a particular type of
object, and it returns a component that adds some common behavior, such as validating
the structure and content of the object using a schema (omitted from my example)
and wrapping the fields in a  with a submit button.

The behavior I would like from the TypeScript type system is:

- typechecking properties at the call site where I use the generated editor component
- typechecking properties inside the HOC where I use the generic editor fields component.

I'm having trouble with the latter. In the example, if you remove `as unknown as P`,
you get:

```
'{ errorMessage: string; } & Omit<EditorProps & CustomFieldsProps, "onSubmit" | "disabled">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'EditorFieldsProps'.
```

I'm trying to tell the type system that I am in fact passing exactly the props required
by `P` by calculating `CustomFieldsProps` and saying:

- The editor must pass `props: EditorProps & CustomFieldsProps`
- And then I'll pass `editorFieldsProps` with a type that should be equivalent to `P`:
  `props` minus `EditorProps` (implied by destructed assignment and `...rest`) plus `EditorFieldsProps`

Does anyone have any idea of how to get this to work? Thanks!

- Similar question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57959774/39396), but that answer yields the same typecheck error since [microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16368).

```js
// https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wcy3ak?file=index.tsx,index.html
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

// Props all editor fields must support, that the HOC provides
interface EditorFieldsProps {
  errorMessage: string;
}

// Props all editors must provide to the HOC instance.
interface EditorProps {
  disabled: boolean;
  onSubmit: () => void;
}

function withEditor<P extends EditorFieldsProps>(EditorFields: React.FC<P>) {
  type CustomFieldsProps = {
    [key in Exclude<keyof P, keyof EditorFieldsProps>]: P[key];
  };
  return function (props: EditorProps & CustomFieldsProps) {
    const { onSubmit, disabled, ...rest } = props;
    const errorMessage = 'Uh oh.'; // Validation is omitted for brevity
    // TODO can we remove this typecast?
    const editorFieldsProps = { errorMessage, ...rest } as unknown as P;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <EditorFields {...editorFieldsProps} />
        <input type="submit" disabled={disabled} />
      </form>
    );
  };
}

type PersonRestProps = {
  [key in Exclude<
    keyof PersonEditorFieldsProps,
    keyof EditorFieldsProps
  >]: PersonEditorFieldsProps[key];
};
type PersonEditorProps = EditorProps & PersonRestProps;

// Props specific to this editor
interface PersonEditorFieldsProps extends EditorFieldsProps {
  person: Person;
  onChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}

// The object we want to edit
interface Person {
  fullName: string;
}

// The editor fields for the person
function PersonEditorFields(props: PersonEditorFieldsProps) {
  const { person, onChange, errorMessage } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={person.fullName} onChange={onChange} />
      <div style={{ color: errorMessage ? 'red' : 'green' }}>
        {errorMessage ? errorMessage : 'No errors!'}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// The editor we want to get automagically.
const PersonEditor = withEditor(PersonEditorFields);

function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState<Person>({ fullName: 'Smith' });
  return (
    <PersonEditor
      person={person}
      onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
        setPerson({ fullName: event.target.value })
      }
      onSubmit={() => alert(`Submitting ${person.fullName}`)}
      disabled={false}
    />
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```